# Javascript xml document and find

Tags: javascript, xml

Let's say I have the following very simple XML fragment:

```
<assignmentOptions>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value="4000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
</assignmentOptions>
<options>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value1="1000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value2="2000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
</options>
```

How can I find all MessageCharacterLimit under `<options>`?
MessageCharacterLimit is not unique, but options/MessageCharacterLimit is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for this:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('options > MessageCharacterLimit');
console.log(a)
```

```html
<assignmentOptions>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value="4000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
</assignmentOptions>
<options>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value1="1000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value2="2000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
</options>
```

You may then loop over the collection you get like this:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('options > MessageCharacterLimit');
for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i].getAttribute('type'));
}
```

```html
<assignmentOptions>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value="4000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
</assignmentOptions>
<options>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value1="1000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
    <MessageCharacterLimit value2="2000" type="integer"></MessageCharacterLimit>
</options>
```

Comment: Just curious. if I do this:  $(a).each(function () { ...... }); then for the a that has just one element each function is called twice. Any idea?